# Good practices for synchronous web services and the backend is asynchronous

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

I'm creating an application on aws using api gateway and other aws services. One doubt that I am is how I will make calls to the backend service being that it is decoupled using SNS and SQS, but my frontend needs the synchronous services.
Can I simulate a synchronous call for asynchronous services using step functions and api gateway? Do I need another service called web api to handle the request and wait for the backend to return?

Comment: Why do you state that your frontend is blocking? Can't you proceed on something like `rxjs` in order to make it async?

Comment: The frontend will not be locked, the problem is how I simulate this synchronous behavior in an asynchronous service using the api gateway. Aws talks about step functions but I did not find any examples.

Comment: *"my frontend needs the synchronous services"*  What does this mean, in specific terms?